# Estimate the remainder in Taylor's formula for a nonlinear map between Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I am trying to get my head around these introduction to Hilbert/Banach spaces. I kind of get the basic, but is still currently struggle to prove the following question.

> Suppose $F(x)=0$ is a non-linear forward operator acting on a pair of Hilbert function spaces $F: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ which has the following properties:
>   $$
> \| F'(x)\|_{\mathcal{L}(H_1, H_2)} \le N_1 \forall x \in H_1
> $$
>   $$
> \| F'(x) - F'(y)\|_{\mathcal{L}(H_1, H_2)} \le N_2 \|x - y\| \forall x,y \in H_1
> $$
>   where $F'(x)$ is the Fréchet derivative. Using the Taylor's formula:
>   $$
> F(x+h) = F(x) + F'(x)h + G(x,h)
> $$
>   show that for the remainder:
>   $$
> \|G(x, h)\|_{H_2} \leq \frac{1}{2}N_2 \|h\|^2_{H_1}
> $$

I know it should be something pretty straightforward (integration by parts was on my bet list) but I apparently couldn't converge to an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u\in H_2$ be a unit vector such that $\langle G(x,h), u\rangle = \|G(x,h)\|$. Consider the function 
$$f(t) = \langle F(x+th), u\rangle $$
Since $f'(t) = \langle F'(x+th) h, u\rangle$, it follows that $|f'(t)|\le N_1\|h\|$ and $|f'(t)-f'(s)|\le N_2\|h\|^2 |t-s|$.  I don't think we need the first of these, actually.

The function $g(t) = f(t) - f(0) -  f'(0)t$ satisfies $g(0)=0$ and $|g'(t)|\le N_2\|h\|^2 t$, hence 
$$
|g(1)| \le \int_0^1 |g'(t)|\,dt \le \int_0^1 N_2\|h\|^2 t\,dt = \frac12 N_2\|h\|^2
$$
which proves the claim because 
$$
g(1) = f(1)-f(0)-f'(0) = \langle F(x+h)-F(x)-F'(x)h, u \rangle
= \|G(x,h)\|
$$